# How to get data from Syslog-NG / Syslog

Tags: c++, sockets, syslog, syslog-ng

I am looking to create a C++ socket app that will listen on a port, and receive data from Syslog and Syslog-NG.  Is there documentation anywhere about how it will come through the socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. The syslog protocol is described in [RFC 5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424). According to [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers), it uses `UDP 514`.